# Integer Formatting as thousand separator first, hundred separator afterwards

Tags: c#

I want to format an integer so that it appears first with the 1000's separator (,), but after that with 100's separator (,)

Input:123456789 
Output: 12,34,56,789

Comment: I can't see what would not be "not real" about this question. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `NumberFormatInfo` that has a `NumberGroupSizes` array that gives you that format:

```
NumberFormatInfo info = new NumberFormatInfo();
info.NumberGroupSizes = new int[]{3,2};

Console.WriteLine(123456789.ToString("#,#", info));
```

Output:

```
12,34,56,789
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar problem (wanted hundreds separators) and this is the only mention of it on google. I agree that it's a real question.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out:
1. the currency depending on the culture,
2. the currency in your wanted format without any cash mark

```
int iValue = 2879068;
string sValue1 = String.Format("{0:C}", iValue);
string sValue2 = String.Format("{0:#,#.}", iValue);
```

but in case if you want to have some cash mark, simply do:

```
{0:$#,#.}//or
{0:#,#.€}
```

Hope it helps,